# What format are most Hearthstone tournaments using?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm getting ready to enter my first Hearthstone tournament. This particular one is using a 3 deck format. But it seems a lot are going to a 4 hero - ban 1 format. **What's the most common format especially if you get into the higher level tournaments?** I'm considering crafting cards which I haven't done yet (have about 1450 dust at this point), and for this particular tournament at least it seems if I can craft class specific cards to make say a Handlock and a Zoolock deck or two different types of Mages like Secret Mage vs Frost Mage, it would be more efficient use of dust.

Do most hearthstone tournaments run a format that requires competitors to use multiple classes? Is this how Blizzcon and the other "majors" work?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that many Neutral cards can be played in several similar decks across many classes. Crafting cards that help any deck with some kind of strategy in mind, no matter the class, is even more dust efficient than crafting class cards that are played in different deck styles of that class. To name a few examples: Leper Gnome is a typical Aggro card, Defender of Argus is played in most Midrange decks, and many high cost Legendaries like Cairne Bloodhoof, Sylvanas Windrunner and Ragnaros the Firelord are commonly played in Control decks. Those are all neutral too ;)

Comment: Please, try to create **one** question per question... You made 3 questions in one (1 and 3 may be crafted into one with some changes, the number 2 is more "What '3 deck tournament' means? Do I need 3 decks of different heroes?")

Comment: @Michel modified the question further for you

Comment: Take a look to see if my edit meets your expectation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several different popular tournament formats and each tournament could run any format it wishes. Most large tournaments are played using the [Swiss tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_tournament) format, and most small (16 or less competitors) use a [Single-Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament) or [Double-Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-elimination_tournament) tournament format. The "Last Hero Standing" match format was the format used most in "televised" tournaments before 2015 including BlizzCon 2014 and the tournaments leading up to it. In 2015, The "Conquest" match format became the more widely used format used most in "televised" tournaments. Both formats have a standard variation and a banning variation.

## Last Hero Standing

- Each player brings 3 decks using 3 unique classes.
- The match is played as a best of 5 games (first player to win 3 games wins the match)
- In the first game of the match, each player secretly chooses which of their decks to play.
- In each subsequent game of the match, the winning player of the previous game must use the same deck. The losing player may pick from any of his or her remaining decks.
- Once a player loses with one of their 3 decks, that deck is considered eliminated and can not be played again in that match.
- With the above rules, a player wins in Last Hero Standing by defeating each of their opponent's decks.

## Conquest

- Each player brings 3 decks using 3 unique classes.
- The match is played as a best of 5 games (first player to win 3 games wins the match)
- In each game of the match, each player secretly chooses which of their decks to play.
- Once a player wins with one of their 3 decks, that deck is considered eliminated and can not be played again in that match.
- With the above rules, a player wins in Conquest by winning with each of their decks.

## Banning variations

- Each player brings 4 decks using 4 unique classes.
- Before the first game, each player secretly chooses one of the 4 classes used by their opponent to ban their opponent from using.
- Players then reveal their bans. A deck using the banned class is considered eliminated and can not be played in that match.
- Standard Last Hero Standing or Conquest rules then resume now that each player has 3 decks using 3 unique classes.

Comment: This is the format called Conquest, right?

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan No, Last Hero Standing and Conquest are not the same, and when I wrote this answer, Conquest either didn't yet exist or wasn't yet widely used.

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan The difference between Conquest and Last Hero Standing is essentially whether the winner or loser has to change decks. To win in Last Hero Standing, you must defeat all three of your opponent's decks. To win in Conquest, you must win with all three of your decks.

Comment: Thanks @ken.ganong. We should add Conquest to the answer, especially now that Blizzard has chosen it for two World Championships in a row.

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan I've updated my answer do to the Conquest match format. Thanks for the push to do so!